# SVG Example not loading the SVG image in other system in iced library for rust

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I tried building the svg example present in the iced libaray. The system in which it was build, it is working as exepected (i.e., the tiger SVG image is loading) but if I'm trying to run it in different machine(laptop), then the SVG image is not loading and only white screen is created.

Please help, how should I proceed in this case:

**Working case:** Machine 1( where this app was built)
[image]

**Failure case:** Machine 2(where I was testing this app)

[image]

My OS is Windows and I'm using the lastest vesrion of iced library.

The code I'm using: https://github.com/iced-rs/iced/tree/master/examples/svg

I tried building the svg example present in the iced libaray. The system in which it was build, it is working as exepected (i.e., the tiger SVG image is loading) but if I'm trying to run it in different machine(laptop), then the SVG image is not loading and only white screen is created.

Comment: You did copy the SVG resource to the appropriate place on the filesystem on that other machine, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iced is trying to load your svg at runtime via `let handle = svg::Handle::from_path`. As this file doesn't exist on the new machine, it's unable to load it. You can instead build the file into the application using rust's `include_bytes!(path)` macro and replacing `from_path` with `from_memory`. The fixed code would look like this:

```
let handle = svg::Handle::from_memory(include_bytes!("../resources/tiger.svg").as_slice());
```

I've tested this code myself before and after moving the .exe to a different location on my computer and it seems to be working.